# Given a date, return the ID of the record that is within the Start and End dates

Tags: map, loop

**Object Name:** Dates__c
**Fields:** Id, Start_date__c (date), End_date__c (date), Week__c (string)

***Objective**: Given a Date e.g **'2022-01-07'** from an object table that has input as so...*

| Id | Start | End | Week # |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A123 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-10 | WEEK 1 |
| A124 | 2022-01-11 | 2022-01-16 | WEEK 2 |
| A125 | 2022-01-17 | 2022-01-25 | WEEK 3 |
| A126 | 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-31 | WEEK 4 |
| A127 | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-10 | WEEK 5 *note: week 1 for that new month* |

*Get the ID of that record that meets my criteria.*

I'm assuming its going to something that includes mapping out the dates for the Dates__c ID

`Map<List<Date>, Dates__c> myMap = new Map<List<Date>, Dates__c>();`

I would love some input on how I can manage to do this.

=============================================================
**Responding to @sfdcfox**
What do you think about this method of finding the answer?

```
Date checkingDate = Date.today();
ID finalDate = new ID();
ID tempDate = new ID();
for ( Date startDate: allDateRanges.keySet() ){   
   if( startDate <= checkingDate )
   {
      tempDate = allDateRanges.get( startDate ).Id;
      continue;
   }
   else{
      finalDate = tempDate.Id;
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can do that, I prefer to use a custom wrapper:

```
public class Period {
    public Date startDate, endDate;
    public Period(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
    public Boolean equals(Object o) {
        Period other = (Period)o;
        return startDate <= other.endDate && endDate >= other.startDate;
    }
    public Integer hashCode() {
        return System.hashCode(startDate);
    }
}
```

Which you can then use as the key:

```
Map<Period, Dates__c> myMap = new Map<Period, Dates__c>();
```

Be aware that if you use overlapping periods, this code might not work as you expect.

Otherwise, consider just using the toStartOfWeek method:

```
Map<Date, Dates__c> myMap = new Map<Date, Dates__c>();
for(Dates__c record: listOfDates) {
  myMap.put(record.StartDate__c.toStartOfWeek(), record);
}
```

As long as you do it consistently, you should get the correct records.

Comment: Can you check the question again, I updated it providing my answer above for better clarification.

Comment: @MeriçAşaner That really defeats the purpose of using the map. Remember that the dates in the keyset are unordered, so you cannot guarantee you'll find the right date if you do this.

Comment: I see, thank you, I really appreciate it. I think I need a bit more clarification to understand what you are doing with the wrapper then. 
I have an sobject called Description__c and it has an Id, Startdate__c and Enddate__c, and Month__c as the fields, Each record has these filled in, and I am essentially be going through a loop with various dates, and I have to get the Id of the description that the date lies within the range for that specific Description__c.Id . The problem I'm having could be the fact that I've never used wrappers with data from an object. Do you have resources on this?